# Did the book principles of physics by halliday solved this question correctly?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, string, textbook-erratum

I like your forums and thank you for being helpful. It's the first time for me to post.
Attached is a question from Chapter 7, Principles of Physics by Halliday. I'm not actually convinced with their solution because:

To get the distance, How can we use the same height twice in two different points on this ramp? Won’t this be wrong?
My solution , instead, is to get theta by tan-1(1.2/3) then dividing 2/ cos theta to get the distance.

[image]
[image: halliday's answer]

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) You might find [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) helpful for typesetting formulas and at least for me, it would be helpful if you edited your question to be more elaborate about your own idea :)

Comment: If you use http://www.onlineocr.net/  it can often be good at converting pictures to text

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not a ramp. Second, the same height can be used because it's unaffected, and remains the same throughout. I don't se any problem in considering the same height. Further, trigonometry allows many different approaches to the same result, so both are correct.